# CentOS 6.8 Stuck at Starting atd [ OK ]

Tags: centos6

My VM CentOS 6.8 is stuck with the message

```
Starting atd: [ OK ]
```

and won't continue to the login screen.

But I can still access it via ssh.

I tried searching for the log files and changing some settings but still can't make it work. Can anyone help me how can I fix this so the login screen will show again?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Could you provide a link to `cat /var/log/dmesg` and `cat /var/log/syslog` output, that can help debug system startup? For larger log files use e.g. http://pastebin.com

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Tombart. There's no file for /var/log/syslog. This is the file for /var/log/dmesg http://pastebin.com/KUQbXCqJ

Comment: I tried reinstalling X11 but every time I try to run startx it shows a "no screens found" error

Comment: The next service after atd is libvirt-guests based on /etc/rc5.d/ is that the one that causing the problem? I'm not familiar with that service.

Comment: I tried to turn off libvirt-guests using "sudo chkconfig --level 5 libvirt-guests off" then reboot but still doesn't work..

Comment: I also tried configuring vncserver to access the gui via VNC VIEWER and it works. I'm just wondering why it won't boot properly to the login screen in the VM(Parallels Desktop)..

Comment: `dmesg` looks ok. Instead of `syslog` CentOS is probably using `/var/log/messages` could you post that? Is there `/var/log/boot.log` or `/var/log/boot.msg` file? And one more thing, what is the output of `xrandr` (running as `root`).

Comment: Yes, here are the files: 
http://mark.ph/messages.txt 
http://mark.ph/boot.log.txt 
`sudo xrandr` outputs “**Can’t open display**” I'm confuse what service/process is causing the problem..

Comment: ok, last thing, what's the output of `ls /etc/rc5.d | tail -n 10`

Comment: Here it is http://mark.ph/rc5.d.txt thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there's a problem with you `xorg.conf`, assuming that it's located in `/etc/init.d/`:

```
mv /etc/init.d/xorg.conf /etc/init.d/xorg.conf.old
```

otherwise try finding its location first:

```
find /etc -name xorg.conf
```

Then `reboot` and the system should start normally.

Comment: I checked the directory /etc/init.d/ but there's no xorg.conf. `find /etc -name xorg.conf` says it's in /etc/X11/xorg.conf. I'll try to edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` if it will work. Thanks @Tombart

Comment: Here is my xorg.conf http://mark.ph/xorg.conf.txt I'm not sure what wrong in the config :(

Comment: just move the config `mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old` it should be auto-generated upon next boot

Comment: I end up reinstalling Parallels Tools and it solved the problem! haha. Thanks for the help!